# AVCaptureSession adding 2 inputs freezes preview layer

Tags: iphone, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession

If I just have the video added as an input, the preview layer works fine, and the video records fine, but if I try to add audio, the preview layer freezes, and video file is corrupted.  What could be going on here that is causing all of this?

```
-(void) record {
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session beginConfiguration];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;

[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}

AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:nil];



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

NSString *archives = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archives"];
NSString *outputpathofmovie = [[archives stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test"] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputpathofmovie];
[session addInput:input];
[session addInput:audioInput];
[session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
[session commitConfiguration];
[session startRunning];
[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
}
-(AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
{
    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
    {
        captureDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}

//  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
if ( ! captureDevice)
{
    captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
}

return captureDevice;
}
```